# How to add the objects of a class in a static List property of same class?

Tags: c#, properties, static

I have a class A and it has 2 normal properties (string properties) and 1 static property (List of type of A). While creating a new instance of Class A, in constructor, I want to add that instance in static list property. I have two questions.

1- Is it possible?

2- If its possible then how can I implement.

I am using following code :

```
public class A {
private string _property1;
private string _property2;
private static List<A> _AList;

public string Property1 {
  get { return _property1; }
  set { _property1 = value; }
}

public string Property2 {
  get { return _property2; }
  set { _property2 = value; }
}

public static List<A> AList {
  get { return _AList; }
  set { _AList = value; }
}
public A( ) {
}
```

}

Comment: Well what happens when you debug the code and run it.. do you get the expected result you are looking for..? if not then report back on any given errors..!

Comment: Can you please show what problem you have with doing "creating a new instance of Class A, in constructor ... add that instance in static list property"? It is unclear what kind of help you are looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1 - Is it possible?

Yes.

> 2 - If its possible then how can I implement.

Initialize the list in a static constructor

```
static A() {
    AList = new List<A>();
}
```

Then add the instance in the instance constructor

```
public A( ) {
    A.AList.Add(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must create the list either in the declaration or in a static constructor.

```
private static List<A> _AList = new List<A>();
```

or

```
private static List<A> _AList;

static A()
{
    _AList = new List<A>();
}
```

In the instance constructor you can then add the new item

```
public A()
{
    A.AList.Add(this);
}
```

---

Note: Static constructors cannot be public, since they cannot be called explicitly. They are called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

See [Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For other type except List will work fine. For List you have to do the following:

```
public static List<A> AList {
 get { 
       if(_AList == null) _AList = new List<A>();
       return _AList; 
     }
 set { _AList = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible and you can implement it inside `factoryMethod`

inside this class, add this method to use for creating a new instance and add it to the list -set constractor to private

```
public static A CreateInstance ()
{
     A instance = new A();
     if(AList==null)
       AList = new List<A>();
     AList.add(instance);  
     return A;
}
```

and if you want to create instance from this class anywhere:

```
A ins = A.CreateInstance ()
```

Answer (score 0):

`AList.Add(this);` in the constructor should add the object instance being constructed to the list.